# How can I change the span between text columns in IEEETran?

Tags: ieeetran

A need to change the distance between the 2 columns of my article, in order to fulfill a conference specification. Namely, I have to set it to 14mm (0.55 inches). However, I can't figure it out.

Right now, I am first assigning values to the margin variables, and then calling the IEEETran class:

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{2cm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{4.4cm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{1.3cm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{1.3cm}
\documentclass[10pt, conference, a4paper, final]{IEEEtran}
```

Comment: Try `\setlength{\columnsep}{14mm}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a minimal example with how you call the class?

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the welcome!! I added the class declaration instructions to the post

Comment: @user124577 Thank you so much, it worked fine! It is fantastic that the solution is so simple. I was starting to get stressed, as I have been looking in the Internet for the solution and wasn't finding nothing at all

Comment: As already commented, `\setlength{\columnsep}{14mm}` just before `\begin{document}` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple. You just have to add `\setlength{\columnsep}{14mm}` to your preamble. That will solve your issue.